# How can I clean this code up better?

Tags: magento, jquery-autocomplete

I have a script inserted into Magento and it does not seem to be behaving properly. Whenever it runs it actually feeds the contents of the html document back into the text box rather than the autosuggestion. Can anyone tell me what the issue seems to be? I think it might be the two functions conflicting, is there a good way to clean this up?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
//<![CDATA[
$j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function(){
        $j("#antique_toys_materials").keyup
        (function() 
            {
                var tag= $j(this).val();
                if(tag!='')
                {
                    $j.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "autocomplete.php",
                        data: "q=" + tag,  
                        cache: true,
                        success: function(result)
                        {
                            $j("#antique_toys_materials").val(result);
                        }
                    }
                    );
                }
                return false; 
            }
        );
        }
    );
        //]]>
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" >
//<![CDATA[
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        $j(window).load(function(){

function calculate() 
{
    var values = [
        $j("#cost").val(), 
        $j("#shipping_paid").val(), 
        $j("#tax_paid").val()
    ];

    var percent_value = $j("#our_markup").val();
//---------------------------// 
    if (percent_value == 285)
    {
    var percent_value = 0;
    }


    var sub_total = eval( values.join('+') );
    var total = eval("sub_total+(sub_total * percent_value)");

    var shortened_total = total.toFixed(2);

    $j("#price").val(shortened_total);
}


$j( document ).ready(function() {
$j(document).on('input', 'input', calculate);
$j(document).on('change', 'select,input', calculate);
});


});
    //]]>
</script>
```

and it hooks up with this

```
<?php
$q=$_GET['q'];
$my_data=mysql_real_escape_string($q);
$mysqli=mysqli_connect('localhost','XXXXXXX','XXXXXXX','XXXXXXX') or die("Database Error");
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT auto_complete_suggestions FROM auto_complete WHERE auto_complete_suggestions LIKE '%$my_data%' 
 ORDER BY CASE WHEN auto_complete_suggestions = '$mydata' THEN 0  
               WHEN auto_complete_suggestions LIKE '$mydata%' THEN 1  
               WHEN auto_complete_suggestions LIKE '%$mydata%' THEN 2  
               WHEN auto_complete_suggestions LIKE '%$mydata' THEN 3  
               ELSE 4
          END, auto_complete_suggestions LIMIT 0,1";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());

if($result)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
      {
       echo $row['auto_complete_suggestions']."\n";
      }
}
?>
```

It works fine in isolation without the noConflict but then when I put it in Magento it seems to need some help and I'm sure that since it's feeding the html file back into it that something's wrong.
Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: If whatever you are building is ever going to be released to the public...please please learn a lot more about developing the Magento platform first.  There really is quite a lot wrong with that code at the moment...

Comment: Alright. Feel like helping me learn? What could I do better?

Comment: Ok, well you should be doing all this in your own module, you should be adding all of the JS from within your modules layout file, you should strictly speaking be using prototype rather than jquery as that is Magento's core JS framework, you should be accessing the database using Magento's methods and definitely not using PHP methods directly or writing raw SQL. Magento is an extremely capable, powerful MVC framework, and while it has a pretty steep learning curve, you really will have a valuable skill under your belt if you learn it well. SO and SE are both great places to learn it!

Comment: Gotcha. I appreciate it. I'm really just in the stages of trying to make the change so I can see it and then working backwards from there. Do you have any tips on getting this to work this way first?

Comment: Come back to me when you are giving the Magento way a go and I'll help you  ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quick guess, but try using the word "jQuery" instead of "$". I had to change a few plugin scripts that interfered with prototype since it too uses the "$".  Once I replaced all instanced of $ with the word jQuery, things started working as I expected.